# Skipping lines of code for unknown reason

Tags: php

```
public function updateFaction()
{
    $this->plugin->getServer()->getLogger()->info("Updating Faction...");
    foreach($this->plugin->getFactions() as $faction)
    {
        $this->plugin->getServer()->getLogger()->info("test");
        if($faction->hasPlayer($this->player))
        {
            $this->faction = $faction->getName();
            return true;
        }
        $this->faction = null;
    }
}
```

When I run this code (using the Pocketmine API) in the console it prints out "Updating Faction..." but never reaches the next line and doesn't print out "test". I feel like there is some stupid error I'm just not seeing here, but it's  got me stumped.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? What does `$this->plugin->getFactions()` contain?

Comment: What data do you get when you try `var_dump($this->plugin->getFactions());` ?

Comment: you can also try to `...->getLogger()->info(count($this->plugin->getFactions()));` to see if you actually have multiple items that you can iterate over

Answer (score 0):

I experience this when I moved a script from php5.5 to php 5.2 server.After several hours, I figured-out that the problem was due to the line termination characters. Hence lines terminating with CRLF get executed and those terminating with CR gets skipped. To solve this problem I simply copied the the script to notepad (or any basic text editor) and save back to the same file and everything worked like it did on the 5.5 server.